# Easier Way to Compare Variables that might be Null SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Is there an easier way to compare variables where either one or both may be Null?
From my understanding if variableA IS NULL and variableB is a not, the <> comparison will not return TRUE. This is an issue for me since I have 30+ fields to compare and would take hundreds of lines if I have to check first if variableA is null then if not check if variableB is null and then do the actual <> comparison.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing equals NULL, not even another NULL.

You could do something like

```
if ISNULL(variableA, -1) <> ISNULL(variableB, -1)
```

`ISNULL` returns the second parameter if the first parameter is null; otherwise it returns the first parameter.  Just be sure to use something for the second parameter of `ISNULL` that isn't going to occur in your dataset (i.e. don't use -1 if variableA or variableB could actually be -1).

If you are comparing strings, you might do something like

```
if isnull(variableA, '#lAsd9082<!') <> isnull(variableB, '#lAsd9082<!')
```

where `#lAsd9082<!` is just some garbage text that would be very unlikely to occur in your data.

### Update

Nulls are a pain to work with, so why not avoid them?  Can you assign a default value to your variables?  If they are parameters in a stored procedure, assign them like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE uspYourProcedure @variableA int = -1, @variableB int = -1
```

If you are defining them yourself, do this:

```
DECLARE @variableA int = -1
DECLARE @variableB int = -1
```

Your comparisons become much simpler if you don't have to account for nulls.

### Update

Ok, you're going to need to do a few checks of the variables, but you can put it into a function so that your code isn't so cluttered.

```
create function dbo.udfVariablesAreEqual(@a int, @b int)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @result bit
    if @a is null and @b is null
        set @result = 1;
    else if @a is not null and @b is not null and @a = @b 
        set @result = 1;
    else
        set @result = 0;
    return @result
end
```

This function returns 1 only if both variables are null or both have the same non-null value.  Otherwise it returns 0.  See it in action here: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ef4df/3

You might squeeze a little more performance out of the function if you use Blam's query instead:

```
create function dbo.udfVariablesAreEqual(@a int, @b int)
returns bit
as
begin
    declare @result bit
    if not ((@a is null and @b is null) or @a = @b )
      set @result = 0
    else 
      set @result = 1
    return @result
end
```

Comment: Ok, I have implemented this but what if variableA is Null but variableB isn't? Technically they still are not equal, but this statement will not return a false. Is the only way around it to have a nested if statements for each variable? I am trying to avoid that since I have 30+ variables to test :( If I can do it in one line, that'll be best. Thank you.

Comment: I think I misunderstood what you were trying to do.  Check out the update to my answer for another idea.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not think I can get around this. The table will be populated with values and often, there are not any values for these field. -1 would not work because that can be a possible valid value for that column. The columns are mainly ints or decimal values which may be positive or negative. Unless there is another way for me to substitute for Null as empty.

Comment: awesome! This works too. And definitely not as clustered as my 200+ lines of statement to check the variables. Performance is a big deal so my final question is would creating a udf and calling the udf 30+ times in my sp be more efficient or should I just have my 200 lines of code in my sp to check be more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: There _is_ a certain overhead involved in calling a udf.  I doubt that it would amount to much in this case, considering the simplicity of the udf.  We're probably talking on the order of milliseconds. If you need to compare these variables hundreds of times a second or something like that, it may be noticeable, but otherwise I doubt it.  You may eke out a little more performance by subbing in Blam's query (I think it gives the same results).  You need to take your sanity into account, when thinking about maintaining a 200 line statement.

Comment: I would say to try it out, and if the performance is unacceptable, then reevaluate your options.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what your aim is, you should look at the `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` operators

[`ISNULL`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) takes a pair of values, and returns the second if the first is null.
eg:

```
ISNULL(null,0) = 0
```

`COALESCE` takes a list of parameters, and returns the first non-null value.

```
COALESCE(null, 1, null) = 1
COALESCE(null, 1, 2) = 1
COALESCE(null, null, 2) = 2
```

Comment: What if all the parameters are null? What would it return? Can I test if it returned a Null or not? I.E. 'IF COALESCE(null,null) IS NULL' Thank you.

Comment: If they're all null, coalesce will return null. alternately, you could add another non null value at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Hundreds of lines to check 30 variables?
This might be faster than isnull

```
where not ( (a is null and b is null) or a = b )
```

Comment: Thank you, I think I found a solution with your help. It's not the prettiest but here it is: IF (@a is not null and @b is not null) and (@a <> @b) OR  ((@a is null AND @b is not null) OR (@a is not null AND @b is null) ) 
BEGIN
 SELECT 'not equal'
END

Comment: And just what about the answer I proposed does not work?

Comment: Well if either @a or @b is NULL and the other isn't, it fails. I.E. : DECLARE @a as int, @b as int
SET @a = 1
SET @b = null
SELECT
'not equal'
WHERE not ( (@a is null and @b is null) or @a = @b )